# Xamarin.Forms ListView deselect item on Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I have problem with deselect item. I want that after again click stacklayout IsVisible = false; but i don't know why my code not working after click again. StackLayout is still visible

```
private bool _isVisible;

public new bool IsVisible
{
  get { return _isVisible; }
  set { _isVisible = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsVisible)); }
}

private void ChallengeList_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.SelectedItem == null)
     return;
   int licz = 0;
   if (e.SelectedItem is MainPage viewModel && licz == 0)
   {
       int li = 0;
       li++;
       viewModel.IsVisible = true;

       if (li == 2)
       {
          viewModel.IsVisible = false;
          licz = 0;
       }
   }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="ChallengeList" SeparatorColor="#3d122c" HasUnevenRows="True"
            ItemSelected="ChallengeList_ItemSelected"  RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression ElementName=Lab, Constant=0,Factor=1,Property=Height,Type=RelativeToView}"
      RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Property=Height,Factor=0.8,Type=RelativeToParent}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  BackgroundColor="#40FFFFFF" Padding="10">
                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="#ff3f50" FontSize="17" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" x:Name="More" Padding="5">
                                    <Label Text="sdfghjkhgfdsfghjkljhgfdsadfghjkljhgfdsaSDFGHJKJHGFDSAsdfghjkhgfds" TextColor="#ff3f50" FontSize="17" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing your variables li and licz and just toggle the IsVisible value, like this:

```
private void ChallengeList_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.SelectedItem == null)
     return;

    viewModel.IsVisible = !viewModel.IsVisible;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the type of `e.SelectedItem` is not `MainPage`, so it will always be null.

### Solution :

#### Create a `ViewModel` :

Add a property in your `ListView` item  to indicate whether the item is currently selected :

```
public class ItemViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    private bool isVisible;
    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get { return isVisible; }
        set { SetField(ref isVisible, value); }
    }
}
```

**BaseViewModel** :

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then in the page's `ViewModel` , you could set the `SelectedItem`'s `IsSelected` value in `SelectedItem` event :

XAML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App7"
         x:Class="App7.MainPage">

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ListView x:Name="ChallengeList" 
          SeparatorColor="#3d122c" 
          HasUnevenRows="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Title}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"  
          RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression ElementName=Lab, Constant=0,Factor=1,Property=Height,Type=RelativeToView}"
          RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Property=Height,Factor=0.8,Type=RelativeToParent}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout 
                    Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    BackgroundColor="#40FFFFFF"
                    Padding="10">

                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" 
                               TextColor="#ff3f50" 
                               FontSize="17" 
                               FontAttributes="Bold" 
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        <StackLayout 
                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                            IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" 
                            x:Name="More" 
                            Padding="5">
                            <Label 
                                Text="QWER" 
                                TextColor="#ff3f50" 
                                FontSize="17" 
                                FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>

                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

</ContentPage>
```

In your `MainViewModel` :

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    private ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> _title;
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { SetField(ref _title, value); }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        var query = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                         .Select(o => new ItemViewModel
                         {
                             Title = $"I am item no. {o}"
                         });
        Title = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>(query);
    }

    private ItemViewModel _selectedItem;
    public ItemViewModel SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedItem != value)
            {
                if (_selectedItem != null) _selectedItem.IsVisible = false;
                value.IsVisible = true;
                _selectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Effect :

[image]